# Cloning Site, <style> in <div>, how do I convert it to regular CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, cloning

I am trying to clone

https://www.sovereignselfdefense.com/

in HTML. The site was built in kajabi. Client wants to move it to a Wordpress theme.

When I downloaded the site, I see code such as:

```
   <div class="container ">
      <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
        
          <style>
  
  #block-1589827030126_0 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  #block-1589827030126_0.block-type--blog .block {
    padding: 0; 
  }
  #block-1589827030126_0.block-type--offer .block {
    padding: 0;  
  }
  #block-1589827030126_0 .block {
    border: 4px none black;
    border-radius: 4px; 
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    #block-1589827030126_0 {
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-right: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      margin-left: 0px;
    }
    #block-1589827030126_0.block-type--blog .block {
      padding: 0;  
    }
    #block-1589827030126_0.block-type--offer .block {
      padding: 0; 
    }
    #block-1589827030126_0 .block { 
    }
}
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    #block-1589827030126_0 {
      text-align: left;
    }
  }
</style>
```

I did some googling and this is outdated incorrect HTML convention.

How would you separate the  tag into an external CSS? I tried separating the CSS into an external stylesheet for the  tag as shown above and the design broke. Client wants the design converted to Wordpress. I figured I would clone the site first, then create a custom wordpress theme. Currently organizing into separate HTML, CSS and JS files. '

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you are able to extract the whole css file, you can still set it to wordpress CSS additional. StackOverflow has a specific website for wordpress [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com) maybe they can give you more advices

The big problem you will have to face will be for the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your are including the correct element with the `id` in your HTML. In your example, the CSS is not selecting any of the HTML tags. `#block-1589827030126_0` is a CSS selector that targets an HTML element with that id. I checked the source code of the site and it's a sibling of that `<style>` tag:

[image]

Other then that, there shouldn't be a problem. It's still CSS so it will work just fine when you load it from the CSS file. Don't forget to link the external CSS in the HTML because original HTML won't have that in it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```